# What's the difference between "I'm in love with her" and "I love her"?

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between "I'm in love with her" and "I love her"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use "in love" indicates a romantic affection, while "love" can also be platonic, between family members, towards pets, or even towards inanimate objects.

If the object for the affection in your sentences was a boat, the second sentence would make perfect sense, but hardly the first. (The first sentence could be used that way, but then it would not be literal, but rather describe a feeling so strong that it would be comparable to romantic love, but still not being of the romantic kind.)

Comment: Is affectuation a new coinage, maybe combining "affection" and "infatuation"? I think I like it. +1 :)

Comment: @Robusto: Well, I'm far from the first to use it according to google, but the previous are probably also mistakes. :)

Answer (score 2):

To add a *psychological* or *spiritual* perspective to this question, the two phrases can be used to contrast *true love* and *false love*.

When you are *in love with someone*, the object of your adoration serves the mere purpose of satisfying your own emotional needs. When you truly *love someone*, you care about the person's needs as a separate individual distinct from you.